# Convert RGBA to RGB in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, type-conversion, python-imaging-library, rgb

What is the simplest and fastest way to convert an RGBA image in RGB using PIL?
I just need to remove the A channel from some images.

I can't find a simple method to do this, I don't need to take background into consideration.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You probably want to use an image's convert method:

```
import PIL.Image


rgba_image = PIL.Image.open(path_to_image)
rgb_image = rgba_image.convert('RGB')
```

Answer (score 16):

In case of `numpy` array, I use this solution:

```
def rgba2rgb( rgba, background=(255,255,255) ):
    row, col, ch = rgba.shape

    if ch == 3:
        return rgba

    assert ch == 4, 'RGBA image has 4 channels.'

    rgb = np.zeros( (row, col, 3), dtype='float32' )
    r, g, b, a = rgba[:,:,0], rgba[:,:,1], rgba[:,:,2], rgba[:,:,3]

    a = np.asarray( a, dtype='float32' ) / 255.0

    R, G, B = background

    rgb[:,:,0] = r * a + (1.0 - a) * R
    rgb[:,:,1] = g * a + (1.0 - a) * G
    rgb[:,:,2] = b * a + (1.0 - a) * B

    return np.asarray( rgb, dtype='uint8' )
```

in which the argument `rgba` is a `numpy` array of type `uint8` with 4 channels. The output is a `numpy` array with 3 channels of type `uint8`.

This array is easy to do I/O with library [`imageio`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) using `imread` and `imsave`.

Answer (score 0):

@Feng Wang Thanks for the answer. You can use the following if your image has an additional first dimension as a batch. You can still use it for a single image. It also works regardless of your order of RGB channels.

```
def compose_alpha(image_with_alpha):

    image_with_alpha = image_with_alpha.astype(np.float32)

    image, alpha = image_with_alpha[..., :3], image_with_alpha..., 3:] / 255.0

    image = image * alpha + (1.0 - alpha) * 255.0

    image = image.astype(np.uint8)
    
    return image
```